# Create Xib file option greyed for UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode6

This is not a "Problem" question, just more like a "Need Info" type.

Why is the option to `"Create a Xib"` not enabled in `Xcode 6.1` when  creating a `UIView` subclass? It lets you create one when creating a `UIViewController` or most other `UIKit` based subclasses.

Is there a reasonable explanation for that?

Comment: I haven't seen this option elsewhere than in UIViewController. which other class offer this option?

Comment: I see it for `UITableViewCell` at least. In any case that is not the point. `UIView` is one of the fundamental building blocks of `UIKit` so I was just wondering why did Apple choose to do this?

Comment: right but nowhere else right?. Still you can create xibs without but I haven't figured out why it's not offered elsewhere

Comment: Is it supported in early version like Xcode 5?

Comment: @gabbler not sure.. I don't have them any more to verify

Comment: I believe the reasoning is that you may not want to create class files just because you're creating a XIB, so instead of linking the creation of the UIView with the XIB, Apple gives you the ability in  XCode to just create a XIB by New File -> iOS -> User Interface -> View. In the case of UIViewController, or UITableViewCell subclasses XCode is generating extra code that establishes the relationship between the XIB and the class. With a simple UIView subclass there's nothing special for it to do.